# bootstrap pill not "tabbing" content

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, nav-pills

I am setting up bootstrap pills on a page and am using the http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage standard formula but I'm getting the `function is not a valid function` error message.  I have:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" role="pilllist" id="myPill">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#all" aria-controls="all" role="pill" data-toggle="pill">Show all</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#car" aria-controls="car" role="pill" data-toggle="pill">Cars</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="pill-content">
    <div role="pillbpanel" class="pill-pane active" id="all">Sample of all</div>
    <div role="pillpanel" class="pill-pane" id="car">Sample for car</div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#myPill a:last').pill('show')
    })
</script>
```

Why am I getting this error message?

Comment: Whats the error message,you could post it too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `.pills('show');` where you should be using `.tab('show');` as seen below:

```
$(function () {
  $('#myPill a:last').tab('show')
});
```

Also, your HTML is incorrect for pills:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist" id="myPill">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#all" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Show All</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#cars" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Cars</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="all">Sample of All</div>  
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="cars">Sample for Cars</div>
</div>
```

Basically, the only mentions of `pill` you should have is your ID (as its name doesn't matter) and `.nav-pills`. Everything else should be `tab`, ie `tabpanel`, `.tab-pane`, etc.

Lastly, the reason you're getting an undefined function error is that `.pills()` isn't a fucntion.

Take a look at this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/mnbHtwc7YG) to see how the tabs work.

Comment: That fixed it!!  I also changed the code in the function to be a:first to display the first item in the list as the default instead of the last.  Thank you very much,

Comment: No problem. Feel free to add this as the accepted answer so others can potentially benefit from your question.